# Alarm triggering independent of time given

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am using the following function `setAlarm()` on `onCreate()` of an Activity to register an alarm (Reminder) for everyday 10:00PM

But each time the activity open, the receiver `AlarmReceiver` is called (On anytime i open the activity).

```
private static AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private static PendingIntent alarmIntent;


 public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    millisecond =  calendar.getTimeInMillis();


    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisecond, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myexampleapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.AlarmReceiver" />
        <service android:name="com.example.service.AlarmService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

You spent quite a few lines setting up the proper time for your calendar variable.  But when you call setInExactRepeating method on your alarmMgr, you are telling it to fire off within a few milliseconds.

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisecond, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Instead you want to tell setInExactRepeating method to fire off at the proper time by specifying your calendar variable converted to milliseconds:

```
  alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand what you have said, I have done the same thing in the above code. In it, I have took the value of calendar.getTimeInMillis() to a variable millisecond and put it on setInExactRepeating . that's all.

Comment: Oh I see that you have saved put the calendar into the millisecond variable now.  My mistake.